# How to preserve original type in match without resorting to asInstanceOf?

Tags: scala, scalaz

The below code is using ZIO, so I've added the scalaz tag, though that may be a bit beside the point. I have a function that takes a type `J` with a typeclass constraint (`Job`):

```
  def execJvm2[J: Job](cmdIn: J): IO[Nothing, Future[RunResult]] = {
    type IOJob = IO[Nothing, J]
    val cmd0: IOJob = omitted(cmdIn)
    val cmd1: IOJob = cmd0.map {
      case cmd : OneShot =>
        memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
        cmd.asInstanceOf[J]
      case cmd: Repl =>
        memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
        cmd.asInstanceOf[J]
      case cmd: ExecFile =>
        memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
        cmd.asInstanceOf[J]
      case _ => ???
    }
    cmd1.map { cmd => poll(cmd.id) }
  }
```

The examples in the pattern match (`OneShot`, `Repl`, `ExecFile`) all are instances of `Job` and have their implicit typeclass instances in scope, though I guess that is a bit beside the point. The main reason this should work without using `asInstanceOf`, to my thinking, is that the type has only been narrowed down in the pattern match from `J` to e.g. `OneShot`, but I would think the compiler would know it is still a `J` as well.

Comment: Does it compile if you call `cmd0.map[J] { ... }` and remove the `asInstanceOf` calls?

Comment: @TzachZohar Good thought, but same result/error.

Comment: I have also tried returning `cmd: J` from each `case` clause, but this just causes the error to happen on the line with `cmd: J`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks a bit worse, but I think

```
val cmd1: IOJob = cmd0.map { cmdJ => cmdJ match {
  case cmd: OneShot =>
    memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
    cmdJ
  case cmd: Repl =>
    memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
    cmdJ
  case cmd: ExecFile =>
    memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
    cmdJ
  case _ => ???
}}
```

should work. And cheating with type erasure a bit, I *think* this should compile and work (but try it):

```
val cmd1: IOJob = cmd0.map {
  case cmd: OneShot with J @unchecked =>
    memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
    cmd
  case cmd: Repl with J @unchecked =>
    memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
    cmd
  case cmd: ExecFile with J @unchecked =>
    memStorage(cmd.id) = JobWithResult(cmd, runIO(runInSystem(cmd)))
    cmd
  case _ => ???
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I really feel bad about not thinking of the first solution as a workaround, but both solutions seem to work. Going with the first result as I feel it is a bit more clear, or at least potentially less surprising.

Comment: Of course, in the first case you can also put returning `cmdJ` outside of the match, if all non-throwing branches return it.

Comment: If the function passed to `map` always returns the existing value then you might as well just use `foreach`

Comment: @Tim the reason I don't think this is true is because of the somewhat counterintuitve nature of working with `IO`; it is building its own execution graph (and makes perfect sense when you realize that). I don't even think `IO` has `foreach` planned, because of that.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I suppose this is a good, concrete example of values not having more than one type ascribed to them in Scala (at least it seems to be the case), with the exception of subtyping. As a further aside, maybe there are staticly typed languages that do support multiple types ascribed to a value(would be curious to know).